# How to download an Excel File with PhpSpreadsheet using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet to create an Xlsx spreadsheet and download directly. Until now to call the php function that create and download the file I'm using the method "". Now I'm trying to call the function with javascript but no download is started and I get only "funny" characters like:

PKk��VG�D�Z�[Content_Types].xml���N�0E�|E�-J��@5��*Q>`�'�UǶl���L����@�nbE�gr=��tW�d�>(k 6�r��V*�,���)�cI�`$hk�`{l:�/�CBb V���9��Bf�RZ_C�W��� ��o���k"�.........

The testing function that is working with the  method:

```
$filename = "2023 - Export Transactions.xlsx";

// make a new spreadsheet object
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
// get cuttent active sheet (first sheet)
$activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Set the value of the selected cell
$activeWorksheet->setCellValue('A1', "test Cell A1");           
$activeWorksheet->setCellValue('B2', "test Cell B2");           


$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

ob_end_clean();

$writer->save('php://output');
exit();
```

What should I do to make working also by calling the testing function with javascript?

Comment: The method that is working is <form>

Answer (score 0):

Your headers seem wrong to me.
The uppercase `T` and the double quotes around the filename are missing.
Try:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```